# SQL Select Distinct on 1 column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table set up like this

```
CompanyName FileName
ABC         abc.gif
ABD         logo.gif
ZBC         zbc.gif
ZVC         zbc.gif
```

I am looking for a query that selects the distinct filename, and orders the results by the CompanyName.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT distinct FileName 
FROM table 
where 
CompanyName in (
    select CompanyName from Table GROUP BY CompanyName
)
```

Comment: What would be the result?

Comment: abc.gif
logo.gif 
zbc.gif

Answer (score 3):

You can only order by the columns returned by the query, so you have to have the company name as part of your results if you want to order by that.  However, since you appear to be cleansing data, I'd suggest something like:

```
; WITH c AS (SELECT CompanyName, FileName, Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FileName ORDER BY CompanyName) FROM table1)
SELECT FileName, CompanyName
FROM c
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY CompanyName
```